# creating a scipy.lil_matrix using a python generator efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, generator, sparse-matrix

I have a generator that generates single dimension `numpy.array`s of the same length. I would like to have a sparse matrix containing that data. Rows are generated in the same order I'd like to have them in the final matrix. `csr` matrix is preferable over `lil` matrix, but I assume the latter will be easier to build in the scenario I'm describing.

Assuming `row_gen` is a generator yielding `numpy.array` rows, the following code works as expected.

```
def row_gen():
    yield numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
    yield numpy.array([1, 0, 1])
    yield numpy.array([1, 0, 0])

matrix = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(list(row_gen()))
```

Because the list will essentially ruin any advantages of the generator, I'd like the following to have the same end result. More specifically, I cannot hold the entire dense matrix (or a list of all matrix rows) in memory:

```
def row_gen():
    yield numpy.array([1, 2, 3])
    yield numpy.array([1, 0, 1])
    yield numpy.array([1, 0, 0])

matrix = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix(row_gen())
```

However it raises the following exception when run:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)
```

I also noticed the trace includes the following:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/lil.py", line 122, in __init__
  A = csr_matrix(A, dtype=dtype).tolil()
```

Which makes me think using `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` will end up creating a `csr` matrix and only then convert that to a `lil` matrix. In that case I would rather just create `csr` matrix to begin with.

To recap, my question is: What is the most efficient way to create a `scipy.sparse` matrix from a python generator or numpy single dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the code for `sparse.lil_matrix`.  It checks the first argument:

```
if isspmatrix(arg1):    # is is already a sparse matrix
     ...
elif isinstance(arg1,tuple):    # is it the shape tuple
    if isshape(arg1):
        if shape is not None:
            raise ValueError('invalid use of shape parameter')
        M, N = arg1
        self.shape = (M,N)
        self.rows = np.empty((M,), dtype=object)
        self.data = np.empty((M,), dtype=object)
        for i in range(M):
            self.rows[i] = []
            self.data[i] = []
    else:
        raise TypeError('unrecognized lil_matrix constructor usage')
else:
    # assume A is dense
    try:
        A = np.asmatrix(arg1)
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError('unsupported matrix type')
    else:
        from .csr import csr_matrix
        A = csr_matrix(A, dtype=dtype).tolil()

        self.shape = A.shape
        self.dtype = A.dtype
        self.rows = A.rows
        self.data = A.data
```

As per the documentation - you can construct it from another sparse matrix, from a shape, and from a dense array.  The dense array constructor first makes a `csr` matrix, and then converts it to `lil`.

The shape version constructs an empty `lil` with data like:

```
In [161]: M=sparse.lil_matrix((3,5),dtype=int)
In [163]: M.data
Out[163]: array([[], [], []], dtype=object)
In [164]: M.rows
Out[164]: array([[], [], []], dtype=object)
```

It should be obvious that passing a generator isn't going work - it isn't a dense array.

But having created a `lil` matrix, you can fill in elements with a regular array assignment:

```
In [167]: M[0,:]=[1,0,2,0,0]
In [168]: M[1,:]=[0,0,2,0,0]
In [169]: M[2,3:]=[1,1]
In [170]: M.data
Out[170]: array([[1, 2], [2], [1, 1]], dtype=object)
In [171]: M.rows
Out[171]: array([[0, 2], [2], [3, 4]], dtype=object)
In [172]: M.A
Out[172]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

and you can assign values to the sublists directly (I think this is faster, but a little more dangerous):

```
In [173]: M.data[1]=[1,2,3]
In [174]: M.rows[1]=[0,2,4]
In [176]: M.A
Out[176]: 
array([[1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 2, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

Another incremental approach is to construct the 3 arrays or lists of `coo` format, and then make a `coo` or `csr` from those.

`sparse.bmat` is another option, and its code is a good example of building the `coo` inputs.  I'll let you look at that yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but both of your suggested approaches assume I have the matrix's shape at hand. This is not the case and since lil is specifically built for line additions, I'm looking for a way to efficiently increase it's size as it's being built.

Comment: What's unknown - number of rows or number of columns? or both?  Collecting the `coo` trio of arrays doesn't require knowing the final size,  But `sparse` matrices aren't designed for incremental growth (nor are sparse arrays).